# Can't install app from APK

Tags: installation, apk

I have a Jadoo4 USB stick that runs on Android, similar to Chromecast. It has an app to watch live TV from East Asia.

I made an APK of that app, but whenever I try to install it on other devices (like my phone), it fails. This is the error that I get on my phone.

[image: App niet geinstalleerd. Het pakket conflicteert met been bestaan pakket met dezelfde naam.]

> Translation: This package conflicts with another package with the same name

The app is provided by the producer. And I don't know if it's specially made for the device. The device doesn't seem very special. It's like a USB/Chromecast but running full Android on it.

The device that runs the app has Android KitKat on it. On my phone, I run Android 7.1. I even tried to install the app virtual Android 4.4 (VirtualBox). First, it seemed that the installation was successful, but after 1 minute, I got the message that the installation failed. On the virtual machine, the error is just "App installation failed".

Any idea why that might be?

Comment: I'm curious how you made an APK of that app. Did you compile it from the source code, or... what? If you want to install it on other device, provided that the original device is rooted, you can pull the original APK file from the device to the PC, and then push it to the other device to install it.

Comment: On the other hand, it seems strange that you got "package conflict" on your phone. Have you installed the APK before from somewhere else?

Comment: Tell us some details how you made the apk. About the error in your android virtual machine with virtualbox: It most certainly is an x86 machine (virtualbox does not support arm) and therefore a completely different architecture, which needs support from the app.

Answer (score 0):

The apk might be corrupted. Try to download it from a different source. Or if you tried to crack it try it with a new pattern(lucky patch).

Answer (score 0):

It means that you might have the same app from another developer or a different app with the name of an existing app.

In that case you have to uninstall the older APK in order to use the new one.

hope it helps .